# How to limit primary y-axis and secondary y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got this code and i want to limit the primary y-axis between 0 and 3500 (the y-axis on the left).

The second y-axis i want a limit between 30 and 65 (the y-axis on the right).

The two y-axis need to be independent of each other.

My code:

```
    library(ggplot2)
SAMLET <- data.frame(Aar=c(2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019),
                     Type=c("FV", "BG", "FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG"),
                     mia_kr=c(1918050,938350.0583, 2312210, 1035680.125, 2842071, 1182431.742, 2910107, 1301530.525, 2795094,1398043.475,2564554,1437696.875,2660361,1473309.825,2598022,1502774.742,2604446,1563715.417,2624976,1607972.45,2716382,1635247.125,2899526,1651717.642,3026961,1676296.525,3175199,1710432.208,3300686,1776903.6,3399871,1864377.058))

SAMLET_2 <- data.frame(Aar=c(2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019),
                       BG=c(0.489221,0.447918,0.416046, 0.447245, 0.500177624,0.560603081,0.553800715,0.578430337,0.600402318,0.612566534,0.601994537,0.569650916,0.55378861,0.538685043,0.538343726,0.548366999 ))


 SAMLET$mia_kr <- SAMLET$mia_kr/1000   

ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x= SAMLET$Aar, y= SAMLET$mia_kr, fill = SAMLET$Type), stat="identity",position = "identity")+
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x= SAMLET_2$Aar, y = SAMLET_2$BG*10000, group = 1, colour = "BLG"),size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::format_format(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./100,labels = scales::format_format(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE),"%" ))+
  
  xlab(" ") +
  ylab("Mia. kr.") +
  labs(title = "My dataplot", caption = "source: calc")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), plot.caption = element_text(hjust = +3), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 0.9))+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("BG", "FV", "BLG"))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#0000ff"))
```

Comment: "The two y-axis need to be independent of each other"; that's not how secondary axes work in ggplot2. The secondary one always needs to be a monotonic transformation of the primary. Have look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3099219/11374827).

Comment: Looked at that post already. And this seems to be possible in answer number 5, the one about weather. 
But can't figure out how to reproduce this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the approach I've outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66055331/11374827), yields the following code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

# Function factory for secondary axis transforms
train_sec <- function(primary, secondary) {
  from <- range(secondary)
  to   <- range(primary)
  # Forward transform for the data
  forward <- function(x) {
    rescale(x, from = from, to = to)
  }
  # Reverse transform for the secondary axis
  reverse <- function(x) {
    rescale(x, from = to, to = from)
  }
  list(fwd = forward, rev = reverse)
}

SAMLET <- data.frame(Aar=c(2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019),
                     Type=c("FV", "BG", "FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG","FV", "BG"),
                     mia_kr=c(1918050,938350.0583, 2312210, 1035680.125, 2842071, 1182431.742, 2910107, 1301530.525, 2795094,1398043.475,2564554,1437696.875,2660361,1473309.825,2598022,1502774.742,2604446,1563715.417,2624976,1607972.45,2716382,1635247.125,2899526,1651717.642,3026961,1676296.525,3175199,1710432.208,3300686,1776903.6,3399871,1864377.058))

SAMLET_2 <- data.frame(Aar=c(2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019),
                       BG=c(0.489221,0.447918,0.416046, 0.447245, 0.500177624,0.560603081,0.553800715,0.578430337,0.600402318,0.612566534,0.601994537,0.569650916,0.55378861,0.538685043,0.538343726,0.548366999 ))


SAMLET$mia_kr <- SAMLET$mia_kr/1000

sec <- train_sec(c(0, 3500), c(30, 65))


ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x= Aar, y= mia_kr, fill = Type), 
           stat="identity",position = "identity", data = SAMLET)+
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x= Aar, y = sec$fwd(BG * 100), 
                          group = 1, colour = "BLG"),
            size = 1, data = SAMLET_2) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::format_format(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ sec$rev(.),
                        labels = scales::format_format(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE),"%" )
  )+
  xlab(" ") +
  ylab("Mia. kr.") +
  labs(title = "My dataplot", caption = "source: calc")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = +3), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 0.9))+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("BG", "FV", "BLG"))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#0000ff"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>